# Can somebody explain this HTML dropdown menu code

Tags: html

I need help explaning this dropdown menu code. I know what the code does bit i have a hard time explaining what does what.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  left: 77.005px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">meny</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <a href="La carte/la carte.html">A la carte matsedel</a>
    <a href="Veckomatsedel/veckomatsedel.html">veckomatsedel</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Also we are not supposed to be paid for a service

Comment: Have a look at what `hover` and `display: none;`vs `display: block;` does - for example https://linguinecode.com/post/css-display-flex-block-inline-block-table

Comment: This question is not showing the efforts made by the user to understand the code. Moreover, the question would not be complete without mentioning the Javascript code or library used and how it is used. Plus the EUR part ;)

Comment: I removed the part about paying as it's irrelevant to the question and against the rules

Answer (score 0):

The first file is a .css file and changes your html's file style (the second one). The .css file changes:

1) the dropbtn meny (it remains fixed, it's the black menu part)

2) the dropdown class (how the all dropping down content will look; it's the whole thing)

3) the dropdown-content (how the dropped down elements will look; it's the grey part (a la carte ... & vecko ...)

4) the dropdown-content a (how the text in the grey area looks)

5) dropdown-content a:hover (when you are hover one of the grey elements, a la carte ... or vecko ..., it will appear "selected" aka white)

6) dropdown:hover .dropdown-content (if you are on the black meny it changes color)

I'm still studying this too, I hope it's usefull for you.